# Different permissions on item creation

Tags: 2013, permissions, list-item

Within SP 2013, is it possible to do the following in terms of permissions :

Two different AD groups : Admins & Users. With only one list.

- When Users access this list, they can add/modify only item that are related to themselves (depending on a people field).
- When Admins access this list, they can add/modify every items they wish in the list.

I think this has already been asked, but I can't find it.

TIA

EDIT : I've just found something.
In the list settings > Advanced settings, there are two checkbox : 
"Read Access" and "Creation/Modification access" where I can choose if users can read all items and modified all items they created or all items. Maybe with this, and some list permissions this will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add Active Directory users group to the Contributors group of the list. And add active directory "Admin" group to the Owners group of the list. Then go to List settings and select Advanced settings. In Create and Edit access, select **Create items and edit items that were created by the user**

Comment: Wow, your answer is exactly what I've just come with ! Yes I think this must be the right way to do this. I'm gonna give a try and come back.

Comment: Ok, thats a good answer. But the problem is, if an Admin create an item concerning a user, this user won't be able to modified this item. This is why I need to set permissions depending on a specific people field

Comment: Maybe a trick would be to create a workflow that modified the "created by" field when item is created ? And now, I could use a little powershell script to modify this field for existing items.

Comment: The answer mentions the OOB way to do it. But if the requirement is to do it on any other person field, then you may also try the event handler code and modify the `Author` field in ItemAdded/ItemUpdated handlers